How to deploy an Model from the Model Catalogue in Azure ML Jobs/Pipelines
I am developing an Azure ML pipeline and want to use a model from the model catalogue. How can I do it without registering as a custom model and reference it directly?
I tried referencing the URI as an input with a custom_model or mlflow_model types:
ce_model:
  type: custom_model
  path: azureml://registries/HuggingFace/models/cross-encoder-stsb-roberta-large/versions/7

However I get the following issue:
UserErrorException:
Message: {
"error_details": {
"componentName": "assetstore",
"correlation": {
"operation": "e1a3c5a9d9483e93fefcde60f8b335f2",
"request": "c7252094b9cf37ed"
},
"environment": "westeurope",
"error": {
"code": "UserError",
"message": "BlobUri is invalid for the asset in request. assetId azureml://registries/HuggingFace/models/cross-encoder-stsb-roberta-large/versions/7, blobUri "
},
"location": "westeurope",
"statusCode": 400,
"time": "2024-05-20T13:57:11.0068354+00:00"
},
"status_code": 400,
"url": "https://westeurope.api.azureml.ms/assetstore/v1.0/dataReference/getBlobReferenceSAS"
}
InnerException None
ErrorResponse
{
"error": {
"code": "UserError",
"message": "{\n    "error_details": {\n        "componentName": "assetstore",\n        "correlation": {\n            "operation": "e1a3c5a9d9483e93fefcde60f8b335f2",\n            "request": "c7252094b9cf37ed"\n        },\n        "environment": "westeurope",\n        "error": {\n            "code": "UserError",\n            "message": "BlobUri is invalid for the asset in request. assetId azureml://registries/HuggingFace/models/cross-encoder-stsb-roberta-large/versions/7, blobUri "\n        },\n        "location": "westeurope",\n        "statusCode": 400,\n        "time": "2024-05-20T13:57:11.0068354+00:00"\n    },\n    "status_code": 400,\n    "url": "https://westeurope.api.azureml.ms/assetstore/v1.0/dataReference/getBlobReferenceSAS"\n}"
}
}

According to this documentation you can deploy
hugging face models either by python, studio or cli.
In you just need to give model id and no need to give type.
Use below cli command to deploy the hugging face models by referencing directly using model id.
endpoint_name="sample-endpoint"
model_name="cross-encoder"
az ml online-endpoint create --name $endpoint_name

cat <<EOF > ./deploy.yml
name: demo
model: azureml://registries/HuggingFace/models/cross-encoder-stsb-roberta-large/versions/7
endpoint_name: $endpoint_name
instance_type: Standard_DS3_v2
instance_count: 1
EOF

az ml online-deployment create --file ./deploy.yml

Output:


@Henrique S. Silva Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?
